# Auto-Layout Constraint: How to make a view maintains its width/height ratio when resized?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

In the interface builder we can pin height, pin width, make two views width equally, but how do I set the constraints so that when a view is being resized, it maintains its width/height ratio?

In my particular case, I have an UIImageView in my view controller. When the view resizes, I'd like my image view to resize, but maintain a 3:2 width:height ratio. Is it possible to do it in IB? Is it possible to do it with code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can add an aspect ratio constraint in IB by control dragging from the view to itself and choosing aspect ratio.

Comment: definitely this is the right answer. however, if you don't like the control-dragging way, click the second icon on the bottom right of your interface builder (the one with the square at the center) and be sure to check the "Aspect ratio" flag.

Answer (score 34):

I don't think you can do that in IB, but in code, it can be done like this (iv is my outlet to the image view):

```
    [self.iv removeConstraints:self.iv.constraints];
    NSLayoutConstraint *con1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.iv attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1  constant:100];
    NSLayoutConstraint *con2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.iv attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.iv attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:.66 constant:0];
    [self.iv addConstraints:@[con1,con2]];
```

This explicitly sets the height to 100, and the width to height ratio to 3:2.

Comment: +1 I haven't found an IB way to do this either. I do it via code, too.

Comment: Update: Xcode 5.1 supports doing that in the IB (finally).

Comment: i think @rudi post now should be marked as accepted answer, because new version of xcode can support this behavior. And almost all developers now use xcode version 5 or above. :)

Answer (score 0):

This guide from Apple really helped me - it outlines two approaches, one where you turn off AutoLayout for certain subviews and set frames directly, and another where you use pure AutoLayout via code.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html