# Xcode 5 Autolayout and making UIView's width equal to height

Tags: ios, autolayout, xcode5

I am using autolayout. I have a UIImageView in IB. I want to make the its width equal to its height.

I learned how to do most of this stuff in Xcode 4. I know how to do it programically, but that produces and error that Apple hasn't fixed yet:

```
'Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews. UITableViewCell's implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super.'
```

So how do I set the this constraint in Xcode 5 Interface Builder?

Answer (score 8):

As Timothy Moose commented, you have the option to keep aspect ratio in Xcode 5.1.

Make sure you have width and height the same. Add the aspect ratio constraint by using control drag to itself.

[image]

It will automatically ensure both height and width are maintained.

Answer (score 3):

In Interface Builder, you can control drag from a view to itself and you'll get Aspect Ratio as one of the options (Width and/or Height are also options, depending on the direction you drag).

The default value is the current aspect ratio of the view, but you can customize this to anything you want in the constraint's attribute inspector.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set that type of constraint in Interface Builder. I also don't think the error you're getting is because of a bug on Apple's side, it generally means that you have an ambiguous layout.

Comment: This is not true. Perhaps this is a new feature in 5.1, but if you control drag from a view to itself in IB, you'll get "Aspect Ratio" as one of the Auto Layout options.

Comment: @TimothyMoose: This is indeed new in 5.1. According to Apple, the full suite of constraints can now be made using Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't verified this but here is a question that answers this.

[Auto-Layout Constraint: How to make a view maintains its width/height ratio when resized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14188187/auto-layout-constraint-how-to-make-a-view-maintains-its-width-height-ratio-when)