# how to set width & height of image using auto layout in xcdoe?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout

I am having a view & image.My view is always in center of the super view.I want add an image around the view.I am able to add the view but the problem is height & width is the issue.So please tell me how set constraints for the height & width of the image view.

Below are constraints for the image view

- Horizontal center
- vertical center
- equal width to parent view(1.7    multiplier)
- aspect ratio

As you can see there is some **space between the view & the image on the right side**.Please tell me how to fix this issue?

Comment: Can you share your project?

Comment: See if you want to look user interface as you have created in Storyboard, you should add four contraint like top, bottom, leading and trailing. Apply this constraint to both control. May be it help you?

Comment: Issue is i want to move the image with view.So if i put the that constraint image will not be moved correctly.

Comment: Add both control into one view and apply constraint relatively.

Comment: can u post screen shots what u want

Answer (score 1):

You can add an aspect ratio constraint in IB by control dragging from the view to itself and choosing aspect ratio.

[Ans here..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14188187/auto-layout-constraint-how-to-make-a-view-maintains-its-width-height-ratio-when?rq=1)

Comment: I don't want to code.I need solution with story board only

Comment: @DheerajKumar study basics of autolayout first. Read this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/83129/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-swift-part-1

Answer (score 0):

Press cmd and select both the images OR view in which the images are. Then go to Editor -> Pin -> Horizontal spacing and set the spacing to 0.

Comment: That does not work at all.My View is shifted to the right side.